# How to compress a specific file using pipeline in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have many CSS files inside `SITE_ROOT/sources/css` and I want to compress only one file in `SITE_ROOT/static/css` using [**django-pipeline**](http://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'sources'),
)

PIPELINE_CSS = {
    'responsive': {
        'source_filenames': (
          'css/smartphones.css',
          'css/tablets.css',
        ),
        'output_filename': 'css/responsive.min.css',
    }
}
```

After running `collectstatic` I see in the `static/` folder the minified file (responsive.min.css) but there is also a copy of all files located in the `sources/` folder and a copy of django admin static files. 
How can I get only the minified file in the STATIC_ROOT folder?

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own `STATICFILES_STORAGE` class, inherited from `PipelineStorage`, which expand the [behavior of `PipelineMixin`](https://github.com/cyberdelia/django-pipeline/blob/master/pipeline/storage.py#L19). Something like this (need to be tested):

```
import shutil
import os.path

from django.conf import settings
from pipeline.storage import PipelineStorage

class PipelineCleanerStorage(PipelineStorage):
    def post_process(self, paths, dry_run=False, **options):
        # Do the usual stuff (compress and deliver)
        res = PipelineStorage.post_process(self, paths, dry_run=False, **options)

        # Clean sources files there
        shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, "static/sources"))

        yield res
```

and use it in your `settings.py` instead of `PipelineStorage`.

Another way could be to run an automated task to clean this directory after each collectstatic. It would be the same idea but on the `manage` command itself.